# Convert a list of pandas dataframes to a dictionary of column-values pairs with occurrences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dataframes and I am trying to convert them to a dictionary of column-values pairs with occurrences where column-value pair is a key and their occurrence in all the list of data frames is a value.

**Input**

```
 >>> list_of_dfs
 [  Ahr(+)  Arid3a(+) Arnt(+)
 1   Klf6    Slc44a2    Mafk
 2  Nr4a1     Zfp771   Zfas1
 3  Baz1b  Arhgef10l  Scarb1,    Ahr(+)  Arid3a(+) Arnt(+)
 1  Rnf220     Zfp771   Clcn6
 2    Klf6  Arhgef10l    Mafk
 3   Nr4a1       Mars   Zfas1,   Ahr(+)  Arid3a(+) Arnt(+)
 1   Ilf3    Slc44a2   Ptprs
 2   Klf6     Zfp771   Rab1a
 3  Nr4a1  Arhgef10l   Lin52,     Ahr(+)  Arid3a(+) Arnt(+)
 1     Smg5    Slc44a2   Lin52
 2    Csde1     Zfp771   Ptprs
 3  Gm13034  Arhgef10l  Smndc1,      Ahr(+) Arid3a(+)  Arnt(+)
 1  Cdc42ep4      Ago4    Clcn6
 2     Srrm2     Hmgb1  Tmem165
 3      Smg5   Sh3kbp1    Bmp2k]
```

**Expected solution**:

```
{('Arnt(+)', 'Bmp2k'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Lin52'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Cdc42ep4'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Nr4a1'): 3, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Zfp771'): 4, ('Arnt(+)', 'Smndc1'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Ptprs'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Klf6'): 3, ('Ahr(+)', 'Srrm2'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Scarb1'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Gm13034'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Tmem165'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Csde1'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Clcn6'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Smg5'): 2, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Sh3kbp1'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Ago4'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Mars'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arhgef10l'): 4, ('Arnt(+)', 'Rab1a'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Mafk'): 2, ('Arnt(+)', 'Zfas1'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Baz1b'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Slc44a2'): 3, ('Ahr(+)', 'Rnf220'): 1}
```

**My attempt**

**Step 1**:

```
# get all the column-value pairs from the list of dataframes

>>> list_of_reg_genes = []
>>> for df in list_of_dfs:
...     tups = [tuple(x) for x in       df.stack().reset_index().values.tolist()]
...     a_tups = [a_tuple[1:] for a_tuple in tups]
...     a_tups_m = [x for x in a_tups if x[1]]
...     list_of_reg_genes.append(a_tups_m)
...
```

**Step 2**:

```
 # use the tuple of column-value pairs as keys in a dictionary and populate the dictionary with zeros 

 >>> list_of_reg_genes_f = list(chain(*list_of_reg_genes)) 
 >>> list_of_reg_genes_f =  set(list_of_reg_genes_f)
 >>> list_of_reg_genes_f
 {('Arnt(+)', 'Bmp2k'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Lin52'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Cdc42ep4'), ('Ahr(+)', 
 'Nr4a1'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Zfp771'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Smndc1'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Ptprs'), 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Klf6'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Srrm2'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Scarb1'), ('Ahr(+)', 
 'Gm13034'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Tmem165'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Csde1'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'), 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Clcn6'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Smg5'), ('Arid3a(+)', 
 'Sh3kbp1'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Ago4'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Mars'), ('Arid3a(+)', 
 'Arhgef10l'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Rab1a'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Mafk'), ('Arnt(+)', 'Zfas1'), 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Baz1b'), ('Arid3a(+)', 'Slc44a2'), ('Ahr(+)', 'Rnf220')}
 >>> list_of_zeros = [0] * len(list_of_reg_genes_f)
 >>> result1 = {(list_of_reg_genes_f) : list_of_zeros for list_of_reg_genes_f, list_of_zeros in  zip(list_of_reg_genes_f, list_of_zeros)}
 >>> result1
 {('Arnt(+)', 'Bmp2k'): 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Lin52'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Cdc42ep4'): 0, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Nr4a1'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Zfp771'): 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Smndc1'): 0, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Ptprs'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Klf6'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Srrm2'): 0, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Scarb1'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Gm13034'): 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Tmem165'): 0, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Csde1'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): 0, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Clcn6'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Smg5'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Sh3kbp1'): 0, 
 ('Arid3a(+)', 'Ago4'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Mars'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arhgef10l'): 
 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Rab1a'): 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Mafk'): 0, ('Arnt(+)', 'Zfas1'): 0, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Baz1b'): 0, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Slc44a2'): 0, ('Ahr(+)', 'Rnf220'): 0}
```

**Step 3**:

```
 >>> # Populating the dictionary by looping through the list of dataframes and checking for the occurence of the keys in the dictionary. 
 ... for df in list_of_dfs:
 ...     for index, (key, value) in enumerate(result1.items()):
 ...         if key[0] in df.columns and key[1] in df[key[0]].values:   
 ...            result1[key] += 1
 ... 
 >>> result1
 {('Arnt(+)', 'Bmp2k'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Lin52'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Cdc42ep4'): 1, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Nr4a1'): 3, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Zfp771'): 4, ('Arnt(+)', 'Smndc1'): 1, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Ptprs'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Klf6'): 3, ('Ahr(+)', 'Srrm2'): 1, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Scarb1'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Gm13034'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Tmem165'): 1, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Csde1'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Hmgb1'): 1, ('Ahr(+)', 'Ilf3'): 1, 
 ('Arnt(+)', 'Clcn6'): 2, ('Ahr(+)', 'Smg5'): 2, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Sh3kbp1'): 1, 
 ('Arid3a(+)', 'Ago4'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Mars'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Arhgef10l'): 
 4, ('Arnt(+)', 'Rab1a'): 1, ('Arnt(+)', 'Mafk'): 2, ('Arnt(+)', 'Zfas1'): 2, 
 ('Ahr(+)', 'Baz1b'): 1, ('Arid3a(+)', 'Slc44a2'): 3, ('Ahr(+)', 'Rnf220'): 1}
```

**Problem with my solution**

But the problem with my solution is it's very slow. It is taking a lot of time for hundred dataframes.

Is it possible that I skip step 1 and step 2 and come straight forwardly to step 3, so that I make the dictionary and populate it as same time?

Comment: Can you simplify and provide a minimal example with expected input and output?

Comment: @Mortz I have already provided the list of input and output, my solution given at the end is working fine but the problem is that it is taking more time. I have posted to find I someone can share an optimal solution so that I can avoid step 1 and step 2. Hence it would take less time to run the whole program.